# Module that warns (a chatbot) about high rate of messages

Tags: python

This is a module I use in chatbot type programs which issue responses to certain private messages from other users. I run incoming messages through this in order to limit the number of responses a user is able to provoke within a short amount of time.

guardian.py

```
import time

class Guardian:
    ''' Anti-flooding mechanism. Tracks how fast users are sending messages. '''

    def __init__(self, flood_limit):
        # Abstract number that represents how quickly you can flood
        self.FLOOD_LIMIT = flood_limit
        # "username": (int) goes down with time, goes up with every message
        self.dict = {}
        self.timer = time.time()

    def update_timer(self):
        ''' Count down the flood timer values for every logged user. '''
        now = time.time()

        time_elapsed = now - self.timer

        self.timer = now

        cooled_down_users = []

        # Check every logged user against the timer and prune cooled-down ones.
        for user in self.dict:
            self.dict[user] -= time_elapsed

            if self.dict[user] < 0:
                cooled_down_users.append(user)

        for user in cooled_down_users:
            del self.dict[user]

    def is_flooding(self, user, limit=None):
        ''' Tallies a user and returns True if they are above the limit. '''
        if limit == None:
            limit = self.FLOOD_LIMIT

        self.update_timer()

        if user in self.dict:
            self.dict[user] += 2

            if self.dict[user] > limit:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        else:
            self.dict[user] = 2
            return False
```

Usage looks something like this:

```
import guardian

anti_flood = guardian.Guardian()

... # Receive some message from the network, etc..

flood_warning = anti_flood.is_flooding(username, OPTIONAL_FLOOD_LIMIT_INTEGER)

if flood_warning:
    reply = "You are sending too many requests too quickly."
else:
    reply = "Here is the response you requested."

... # Send a message back, change something based on the request, and so on.
```

I have tried to make the module more or less general purpose, so that it could be used for other, similar tasks, such as kicking / banning users who flood a chat room. However, the way it is actively running through its internal dict of users on every message might cause issues in high traffic applications.

I can also imagine a potential issue if many different users conspire to flood the script with messages, therefore bypassing the individual limit.

I'm **primarily** looking for critique and guidance on readability, usability, generally anything pertaining to having my code read and used by other developers, but design, functionality, optimization, **anything goes**, of course.

My aim is to take a step toward becoming a useful programmer in the future, rather than just making stuff that never leaves the confines of my hard drive.

Answer (score 9):

- `is_flooding` is apparently triggered by the particular user's action. However, it calls `update_timer`, which affects much wider community. This seems wrong. I recommend keeping each user's activity along with the user's instance, and test only her, along the lines of

  ```
  def on_message_received(user):
      user.update_tally()
      if user.flooding():
          user.warn_and_ignore_message()
      else:
          user.proceed_normally()
  ```
- The (anti)-idiom

  ```
      if self.dict[user] > limit:
          return True
      else:
          return False
  ```

  is a long way to say

  ```
      return self.dict[user] > limit
  ```
- The significance of `2` in dictionary updates is very unclear.

Comment: That's a good recommendation, and I had considered doing it that way. I weighed the options against each other when I wrote this script and here was my judgement, if you'd like to offer some insight: In the version I wrote, it is indeed the case that every time any user passes through the scripts, every entry in the dict gets affected. Downside: It's a little slower, computationally. Conversely, in your version, users keep getting added to the dict, and there's no mechanism to remove them. It could (conceivably) lead to a huge dict of previous users who never sent another message.

Comment: Users are added to the dict (or some other container) as they log in, and are removed as they are logged out. I presume you need to track them anyway.

Comment: The script only tracks users who are sending messages (to it, in my implementation). There's no need to track them beyond that, in my use case, and I don't necessarily have the information about who logs in or out of the network.

Answer (score 7):

### General PEP-8 recommendations

- Only use `ALL_CAPS` variable names if they're constants.
- Although opinions differ on this, you should, for readability, go easy on whitespace. For example:

  ```
  now = time.time()

  time_elapsed = now - self.timer

  self.timer = now

  cooled_down_users = []
  ```

  Could be rewritten to:

  ```
  now = time.time()
  time_elapsed = now - self.timer
  self.timer = now
  # Possibly removing this blank line, too
  cooled_down_users = []
  ```

### General advice

- Make variables and functions private, where needed. This is not neccessary, 
  but it will make it easier for others to interact with your code. In Python, to 
  mark something as 'private', name it following `_starts_with_underscore`.
- Avoid using `== None`. You should use `is None`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python/134659#134659).
- `self.dict` is not a good name for a variable (and the same goes for `list`, 
  `tuple`, etc.). In general, you should avoid using reserved keywords for 
  variable and function names. In this case, perhaps use `self.users` or `self.user_dict`.

### Rewritten

I've rewritten your code, and added comments to explain the changes I made.

```
"""
A Python module to check for spam and flood messages.

Source: 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165962/module-that-warns-
a-chatbot-about-high-rate-of-messages/

Last edited:
June 16th, 2017

Original author:
Holistic IT (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/141382/holistic-it)
"""

from time import time


class Guardian:
    """Main class for Guardian anti-flood mechanism.

    Functions:
    * __init__(): Initialize a new Guardian instance.          
    * _update_timer(): Private function.
    * is_flooding(): Check if a user is flooding.
    """

    def __init__(self, limit, users):
        """Constructor.
        Set up a new Guardian instance to monitor a chat room /
        similar environment.

        Arguments:
        * limit: [int] The amount of seconds a user
                 should wait in between actions.
        * users: [dict] A dictionary containing a list
                 of users and a numerical value, where
                 user:numerical_value.
        """
        self._limit = limit
        self._users = users
        self._timer = time()
        self._update_timer()

    def _update_timer(self):
        """Updates self._timer variable.<br />
        Private function.
        """
        self._timer = time() - self._timer
        # Simplified this to a one-liner
        for user in self._users:
            self._users[user] -= time_elapsed

            if self._users[user] <= 0:
                self._users.pop(user)
        # Since all you really want is to remove users that are not flooding
        # from the list, you don't need a temporary list, just use pop().
        # Note that this permanently removes the user from the list

    def is_flooding(self, user, limit=None):
        """Checks if a user is flooding.

        Arguments:
        * user: [str] The name of a user in self._users.
                Throws KeyError if not found.
        * limit: [int] A custom limit for :user:. If no
                 argument is given, the standard limit
                 applies.
        """
        self._update_timer()
        if limit is None:
            limit = self._limit

        try:
            return self._users[user] > limit
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError("User {user} not found.".format(user=user))
```

Comment: Excellent advice on the formatting and conventions! In your rewritten version, the functionality is a little different. For one, nobody ever gets added to self._users, so the script will never return True. Furthermore, `is_flooding` will raise a KeyError every time for that same reason, so my example usage at the bottom would simply crash.

Comment: Oh no... don't do that. That had all the good formatting and stuff. It was very helpful...

Comment: I've rolled it back, just know there's bugs.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware. I'm just looking at the way it's written. I'll be going through it and looking up all of these conventions to better understand them.

Comment: On the subject of two blank lines: PEP8 says "Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a single blank line."

Comment: You are right. My bad.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to move this thread to the chat? Like I said, I'm going through the whole answer point by point for learning purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60642/discussion-between-coal-and-holistic-it).